# Is there a Chinese Intelligence Agency? Why is it not well known?

Tags: china, espionage

I'm curious to know why we never hear of an intelligence apparatus of China, as we do of CIA or KGB or FSB (Russia). British MI5/6, Mossad even Indian RAW make headlines or at least one finds them mentioned in news.

But never CIA (China Int. Ag., pun, of course). With China's rise, surely, they must be investing in that direction. From purely espionage view point, where do they stand?

Comment: Probably a better question for the Politics SE site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason is that they don't operate using [conventional means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_intelligence_activity_abroad) or targets. A lot of their military spying is through hacking or other computer operations rather than human intelligence. They don't have many military men or "professional" spies working abroad.

These people are at home coordinating the efforts of "patriotic" civilians, students, exchange professionals, other visitors, etc. These efforts are directly mainly at economic targets (although they won't pass up military targets).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the People's Republic of China has the [MSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_State_Security_(China)), and before that, the [CDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Department_of_Social_Affairs).

Other China (Taiwan) has the [NSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Security_Bureau_(Taiwan)).

Answer (score 1):

Of course they have. A whole ministry, no less. Very few states have no intelligence organizations.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_State_Security_(China)